# how to prevent git from tracking a single line?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a projects with few versions, each one of them obviously runs on its own git branch.
the project has a tracked configuration file (google app engine's app.yaml) which, among other things, holds the version name.

I'd like to jave a way to tell git to ignore that line when merging bug fixes from one branch to another.

is there an intelligent way to so so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do that. Git supports [custom merge drivers](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) for cases like this.

In your merge driver, you should check out all three versions of the file and remove the line in question in all of them. Then run [`git merge-file`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html) on the result. Some pointers may also be found in the [`git merge-one-file` helper](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-one-file.html). When you are done, readd the line from the `ours` version to your result.

If you really want to **not track** that line, you can use [smudge and clean filters](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) for that. But I don’t think that’s what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No**.

Fun answer: [git](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/git) in UK English means *an unpleasant or contemptible person*.

Actual answer:

Git was designed for tracking the changes in your projects/repository and not individual files.

> Git's design is a synthesis of Torvalds's experience with Linux in
>   **maintaining a large distributed development project**, along with his
>   intimate knowledge of file system performance gained from the same
>   project and the urgent need to produce a working system in short
>   order.

I don't think there's any way of doing it (which would be coined intelligent).

<sub>PS: The reply might be offensive to some, but the ideology behind git was to "not to" have people work on individual files' movement.</sub>

One thing you can do is, create diffs between branches and ignore the particular file entirely while generating/merging the patches. Don't know if it is actually applicable/beneficial.

Another solution you can try is: ["Merge" Specific Files from Another Branch](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/)

Comment: the problem of having not-to-be-merged diffs in separate branches is so common it must have an intelligent solution. I was thinking of some hook that will generate this file from a template but that's too complicated for a fairly simple requirement

Comment: i do not know about "google app engine's app.yaml", but the problem arises in similar form when there is a release and e.g. the release notes are updated. the solution/workaround i have seen is that these changes go in a single separate commit and merge is done with the commit preceding this release commit when reintegrating the changes to master.